# How can undo ipynb tab in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally deleted the notebook .ipynb tab in VsCode <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> doesn't work. I don't know how to undo it, It was a long program I don't want to write it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> works only if you deleted something inside the cell, but the cell is still there.

To recover an entire deleted cell just do:
<kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.